# show tables like 'a_',only start with a and end with digital

Tags: mysql

I've got database with tablenames

````
```a_1,
   a_2,
   a_3,
   ab_1,
   ab_2,
   abc_1,
   abc_2,
   ...```
````

And now I need to get tables a_1,a_2,a_3...,  only start with a and end with digital

Comment: Are you asking how to use `show tables like ...`?  Otherwise I am not really sure what you are asking.   You can use `select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name rlike '^a.*[0-9]$'`

Comment: i only want to get tables name, a_1,a_2, a_3...,use show tables like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db-name' AND TABLE_NAME rlike 'a_.*[0-9]'

Comment: i only want to get tables name, a_1,a_2, a_3...,can use show tables like ?

Comment: "show tables like" supports simple wildcard %, _, it is not able to match digits only. I think you have to use rlike to select table names from information_schema.tables